# itunes music developer app referral

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, referrals

How do App developers get a referral bonus for sending users to the itunes store to purchase a song? If i'm not mistaken theres a 30% referral bonus, so to speak, just trying to determine how to tap into that.

Comment: I think this is more of a question for Apple and not a coding question per se.

Comment: i think its very specific to coding and developers as a whole, as its asking how to programmatically attach a app referral link using linksynergy (as it turns out).  Well at least you couldn't close the question before Dyson helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/). I'm pretty sure the referral fee is 5%. Not 30%. It may depend on the type of media you're getting the commission on.

Comment: well the 30% was more hearsay than anything, thanks!